# Sleepy Betta in heated 10gal tank

Tags: health, fish

I have a Betta fish in a 10gal/37.5l heated (78°F/25.5°C) tank. I tested my water and it's perfect I also do regular water changes once a week.

My problem is that all my Betta does is sleep and I don't know if there is something wrong with him.

I have another Betta in a different 10 gal aquarium. And he's fine. The sleepy betta does eat but other than that, he stays at the bottom of the tank.

Comment: How long have you had this Betta? Was your tank fully cycled before putting him in? Is there alot of uneaten fish food on the bottom? Is there a chance you purchased him already like this? What did you test for and what were the results? Thanks

Comment: That is what they do. he is waiting for a female or something like a mosquito larva .

Comment: Please see  paragraphs labeled recognizing behavior of sick Betta  https://www.earthsfriends.com/betta-fish-diseases/